# How to assign JSON dataset to var using asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asynchronous

I have a problem, I have written a nice function that returns a dataset from a local JSON file on my server. I wish to use the returned data by setting this to a variable to I can pass it to other functions later however due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX my variable will always be set to `undefined` as the variable is set before the dataset from my function is returned. I don't want to set my variable inside my `fetchData` function, what is the best way to assign my variable value here whilst waiting for the `fetchData` function. Should I return some kind of callback or does this need a promise of some kind or should I set the async argument of `window.XMLHttpRequest.open` to `false`?

```
    'use strict';

function fetchData() {
    var prodData;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        prodData = new XMLHttpRequest();
        prodData.overrideMimeType('application/json');
        prodData.open('GET', 'products.json', true);
        prodData.send();

        prodData.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (prodData.readyState === 4 && prodData.status === 200) {
                return prodData.responseText;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        };
    }
}

var myData = fetchData();

// later I shall use this data like so...

doSomethingWithMyData(myData);
```

Comment: Why can't you use callback function?

Comment: Read @Benjamin Gruenbaum answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the [promise-based asynchronous pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/JavascriptPromise.html).

That is, you provide an object as return value of `fetchData` that allowing you to subscribe to asynchronous operation progress:

```
fetchData().done(function(data) {
  // Do stuff when async operation completed successfully
});
```

[jQuery has a decent implementation for this pattern.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)